# php continue to get rest value in a loop

Tags: php, json, loops

I have some json data, i want re-install it after match some condition.

```
$mm='a';
$nn='104';

$jn=array();
$j2='[
{"a":"c","n":"103","t":"rfg"},
{"a":"a","n":"104","t":"bmf"},// <- find the data, re-install from the next line
{"a":"b","n":"105","t":"tit"},
{"a":"a","n":"106","t":"iou"},
{"a":"b","n":"107","t":"wdf"}
]';
$t2=json_decode($j2);

foreach($t2 as $d2){
    if($mm==$d2->a&&$nn==$d2->n){
        continue;
    }
    $jn['a']=$d2->a;
    $jn['n']=$d2->n;
    $jn['t']=$d2->t;
    $p.=json_encode($jn).',';
}

echo '['.substr($p,0,-1).']';
```

I need return json data as `[{"a":"b","n":"105","t":"tit"},{"a":"a","n":"106","t":"iou"},{"a":"b","n":"107","t":"wdf"}]`

Comment: And what is yiur error or what? (except wrong `json_encode` usage)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The following code will do the job
Append the string only after finding a match.

```
$mm='a';
$nn='104';
$jn=array();
$j2='[{"a":"c","n":"103","t":"rfg"},{"a":"a","n":"104","t":"bmf"},{"a":"b","n":"105","t":"tit"},{"a":"a","n":"106","t":"iou"},{"a":"b","n":"107","t":"wdf"}]';
$t2=json_decode($j2);
//echo "<pre>";
//print_r($t2);
//exit();
$append = false;
$p='';
foreach($t2 as $key=>$d2){

    $jn['a']=$d2->a;
    $jn['n']=$d2->n;
    $jn['t']=$d2->t;
    if($append){    
      $p.=json_encode($jn).',';
    }   
    if($mm==$d2->a&&$nn==$d2->n){
        $append=true;
    }
}

echo '['.substr($p,0,-1).']';
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you understand that.

```
<?php
$mm='a';
$nn='104';

$jn=array();
$j2='[
{"a":"c","n":"103","t":"rfg"},
{"a":"a","n":"104","t":"bmf"},// <- find the data, re-install from the next line
{"a":"b","n":"105","t":"tit"},
{"a":"a","n":"106","t":"iou"},
{"a":"b","n":"107","t":"wdf"}
]';
$t2=json_decode($j2);

$i=0;
foreach($t2 as $d2)
{
    if($mm==$d2->a && $nn==$d2->n)
    {
        $jn['a']=$d2->a;
        $jn['n']=$d2->n;
        $jn['t']=$d2->t;
        if($i==1)
        {
            $p=json_encode($jn).',';
        }
        else
        {
            $p.=json_encode($jn).',';
        }
    }
    $i++;
}

echo '['.substr($p,0,-1).']';
```